# How to install some packages from "unstable" Debian on a computer running "stable" Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, aptitude

On a computer running "stable" Debian, when trying to install a package which is in the unstable list on the Debian web site using the `aptitude install <package>/unstable` command, I get output similar to this:

```
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "<package>"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "<package>"
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

What can I do to be able to install "unstable" packages? (I thought of adding the repository to `sources.list`, but I don't want everything to start being installed from "unstable").

So: how can I install unstable packages (with using `/stable` at the end of the package name)?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671 for an in-depth answer to this question.

Comment: Short version: Don't. Longer version: **do not do this**. Use backports if you have to, but don't mix stable/unstable.

Comment: I believe this is called a "FrankenDebian": "Debian Stable should not be combined with other releases. If you're trying to install software that isn't available in the current Debian Stable release, it's not a good idea to add repositories for other Debian releases. The problems might not happen right away, but the next time you install updates." From [Don't Break Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian).

Comment: @Shadur Answering "don`t" to a question is useless at best.

Comment: @silidrone It most emphatically is not, when the question in itself is a *terrible idea*.

Comment: @Shadur I will have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You do need to have `unstable` listed in your [`sources.list`](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList). Otherwise apt just won't find the package.

To avoid `unstable` packages being pulled in, you have two ways.

- The easy way is to add a `Default-Release` clause to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` (or to a file under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`, e.g. `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/my-default-release`).

  ```
  APT::Default-Release "stable";
  ```
- The hard way is to use [APT preferences](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences). In `/etc/apt/preferences`:

  ```
  Package: *
  Pin: release o=Debian,a=unstable
  Pin-Priority: 10
  ```

Note that for most of the lifetime of a Debian release, it's not practical to install most packages from unstable on a stable system, because they'll pull in a lot of libraries from unstable, and you'll end up with an unstable system. If you want to run unstable, it'll save you trouble to just target unstable (or testing). It's best to stick to a single release, or testing with the occasional unstable if you're feeling daring. And of course, on a production system, stick to stable.

If you're running stable but you need a newer version of one application, first look if there is a [backport](http://wiki.debian.org/Backports) for them. Otherwise, if you want to install a package from unstable but not have to pull in its dependencies, try getting the source from unstable and recompiling.

```
apt-get source foo=1.42
apt-get build-dep foo  # pulls the dependencies of foo in stable but that's often good enough
dpkg-source -x foo_1.42.dsc
cd foo-1.4210126#10126
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -b -nc
dpkg -i ../foo_1.42_$(arch).deb
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning backports, but you really should point out more emphatically that mixing stable/unstable is really bloody dangerous and if you don't know what you're doing you *should not do this on a production system*.

Comment: Adding "Default-Release" thinky to a file under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` didn't work. I would go for adding files with pin priority in the `/etc/apt/preferences.d` folder. It's fine to mixing stable with testing if you know what you are doing. Stable with unstable is also possible (also assuming you know what you are doing).

Comment: Also during `dpkg-source` I get the error: `gpgv: unknown type of key resource 'trustedkeys.kbx'`. I already tryied to import the public keyring.