# How to get gcc-4.7 to /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 as second gcc in Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, gcc, matlab

I would like to keep my gcc 4.9 but let Matlab use gcc 4.7 because Stable Debian does not support 4.7, as observed in the thread [Debian Jessie: Why gcc-4.7 conflicts with gcc-4.8?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165889/16920) 
I do the following but nothing in Jessie because [Matlab](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-default-compiler.html) 2016 wants gcc 4.7.x

```
# https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gcc-4.7
apt-cache search gcc-4.7
```

However, I think `apt-get` is not the way to go because I just want to get gcc-4.7 in my system for Matlab, not for any other purpose. 
Example of the warning when using wrong gcc in Matlab

```
MEX completed successfully.
Building with 'gcc'.
Warning: You are using gcc version '4.9.2'. The version of gcc is not supported. The version
currently supported with MEX is '4.7.x'. For a list of currently supported compilers see:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release.
```

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question as stated, but it solves the underlying problem: you can upgrade to Matlab 2016b, which [supports GCC 4.9](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2016b).