# Debian Testing - apt package has unmet dependencies when installing Virtualbox 6.0 or 6.1

Tags: debian, apt, virtualbox

This might not be the best place to ask this question (if not please direct me elsewhere) however I have a problem with unmet dependencies when attempting to install Virtualbox 6.0 or 6.1 on a Debian Testing system.

My guess - although I don't know if this is the case - is that `libvpx5` is not available in `testing` for some reason.

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-6.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-6.0 : Depends: libvpx5 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: linux-headers-generic but it is not installable or
                              linux-headers-generic-pae but it is not installable or
                              linux-headers-686-pae but it is not installable or
                              linux-headers-amd64 but it is not going to be installed or
                              linux-headers-2.6-686 but it is not installable or
                              linux-headers-2.6-amd64 but it is not installable or
                              linux-headers but it is not installable
                  Recommends: linux-image but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# virtualbox
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian buster contrib
```

I assume adding `buster` is the correct thing to do here, despite the fact that I am tracking the testing branch.

How should I resolve this problem, or is it really impossible to fix?

Answer (score 5):

That VirtualBox package is intended for Debian 10, not Debian testing (and even then, it’s really designed for Ubuntu). There are two ways to fix this:

- add Debian 10 to your sources — `libvpx5` is available there;
- add Debian unstable to your sources, which is a good idea anyway when you’re tracking testing, enable `contrib`, and install [the `virtualbox` package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/virtualbox) which is available there.

To do either of those, edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to add a line specifying that your default is Bullseye (the current Debian testing):

```
APT::Default-Release "bullseye";
```

then add the extra repositories to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`; for example in `/etc/apt/sources.list` you might end up with

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
```

if you were to track Bullseye and unstable.

See also the best practices in [the Debian testing guide](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586476/304637), `libvpx5` is available in Debian 10 (`buster`). You can install it by adding that to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
```

Then run `apt update && apt-get install libvpx5`.

However even after installing this and getting past the dependencies problem, I ran into a bunch of mysterious errors trying to install `virtualbox-6.1` on bullseye. I don't have the full error text, but it said to look at `/var/log/vbox-setup.log` for details, which contained:

```
Building the main VirtualBox module.
Error building the module:
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/5.10.0-1-amd64/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j16 modules
make[1]: warning: -j16 forced in submake: resetting jobserver mode.
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-1-amd64 -f /usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-1-common/Makefile modules
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-1-common/scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0 \
single-build= \
need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1
...
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-1-common/Makefile:1817: /tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-1-common/Makefile:185: __sub-make] Error 2
make: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile-footer.gmk:117: vboxdrv] Error 2
```

I tried everything I could think of to install it, including installing the [unstable channel package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/virtualbox) and manually installing the [generic Linux build](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/VirtualBox-6.1.16-140961-Linux_amd64.run), neither of which worked. What finally worked was following the instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8051/304637) to get the source of the unstable package, build it from source, and install it. Note that it took a long time to build.

```
apt-get source virtualbox=6.1
apt-get build-dep virtualbox=6.1
dpkg-source -x virtualbox_6.1.16-dfsg-6.dsc
cd virtualbox-6.1.16-dfsg
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -b -nc
dpkg -i ../virtualbox-dkms_6.1.16-dfsg-6_amd64.deb ../virtualbox-source_6.1.16-dfsg-6_amd64.deb
dpkg -i ../virtualbox_6.1.16-dfsg-6_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Since asking this question, I've started using KVM/QEMU

For those reading in future I would recommend ditching virtualbox and using KVM/QEMU with `virt-manager`

Learning curve is a bit steeper but you can do so much more with this method