# How to patch a debian package?

Tags: debian, debugging, patch

I have Debian stable and I have found some weird bug which [was already fix](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/issues/45).

The fix were merged into the stable branch which version was
`gnome-settings-daemon 3.32.1`
but I have
`gnome-settings-daemon 3.30.2-3`
So, how can I use the patch without breaking my system?  I have to install from where? Backports?

I check versions with apt but I don't see any useful here:

```
/home/user-> apt-cache policy gnome-settings-daemon
gnome-settings-daemon:
  Installed: 3.30.2-3
  Candidate: 3.30.2-3
  Version table:
 *** 3.30.2-3 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Debian Packages page for gnome-settings-daemon](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gnome-settings-daemon), the latest version for `stable` (buster) is `3.30.2-3` (which you already have installed).

However, for `testing` (bullseye) and `unstable` (sid), version `3.38.1-2` is available. Thus, you could install only the missing packages from those newer releases, as described here: [How to install some packages from “unstable” Debian on a computer running “stable” Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8051/388354)

Backports and compiling from source are further options (also described in the answer linked above).

Comment: A very detailed description of the different approaches (install unstable, backports, etc) and their advantages/disadvantages is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112160/388354

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

[`backports.debian.org` does not seem to include the package `gnome-settings-daemon` for `buster`.](https://backports.debian.org/changes/buster-backports.html)

The `testing` branch currently has version 3.38.1-2, which is quite a bit newer than what you need.

The recommended way would be to backport the patch yourself.

You would have to:

- install any development packages required to build `gnome-settings-daemon`:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-settings-daemon
```

- get the **source code** for gnome-settings-daemon

```
apt-get source gnome-settings-daemon
```

- apply [the patch](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/commit/cea632bf682760e80654df19cfef6206efca868a)

```
cd gnome-settings-daemon-3.30.2/
curl 'https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/commit/cea632bf682760e80654df19cfef6206efca868a.diff' | patch -p1
```

- document the addition of the patch into the package changelog (technically you could omit this if you're only using the package for yourself, but it would be a good to make this a habit if you plan to become a package maintainer)

```
dpkg-source --commit  # this will ask you to write a changelog entry
```

- build the binary package(s):

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
```

- and finally install the resulting binary packages:

```
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i gnome-settings-daemon_3.30.2-3_amd64.deb gnome-settings-daemon-common_3.30.2-3_all.deb
```

- If you wish to make the change effective without logging out, you'll need to kill any existing `gsd-media-keys` process so that gnome-settings-daemon will restart it using the new binary:

```
killall gsd-media-keys
```